# How can I load data when I click in another box?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an autocomplete on my page where I use it as a search. I want to be able to select an item that appears in the autocomplete and then when the user clicks another box it will do a postback and if there is data for the one selected, it will populate the other fields for that chosen selection.

So what I am asking, is how would I go about doing a postback when the user clicks into another textbox on the screen?

Comment: Or better still, when they click outside of a certain box e.g. txtSearch

Comment: provide more detail which auto complete you are using etc.

Comment: show your code you have tried

Comment: will you show your  html code

Comment: I didn't post the code because theres a lot of it, but essentially, just imagine a page with two textboxes, I want to type something in the first one, then when I click out of the first one I want to do a postback and populate the second.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use event from textbox (TextChanged) inside this event put your code to verify if this data is correct. Don't forget put property AutoPostBack from textbox in True. This action only can be use if the data in textbox change if for example you put

My Dog

and data not exists if you change focus nothing will happen until you change the data for example

My Cat